# How to check Google Colaboratory's IP Address and port?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Can anyone tell how could I check my google Colaboratory's hosted runtime's IP Address and Port ?

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I need it for distributed training of deep learning models. That's fine for you?

Comment: It's not a matter if it's fine with *me*, but of correct usage. Tags are about the *content* of a question, not its *context*; the fact that you may need help debugging, say, a sorting algorithm to be subsequently used in a spaceship does not in itself qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`. All in all, the exact reason *why* you need this is irrelevant to the question itself, and must not find its way into the tags.

Answer (score 4):

```
#Gives ip address
!hostname -I

#gives ip address
!curl ipecho.net/plain

#Gives ip addresses with port numbers
!sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```