# It is possible to assign the google colab notebook name to a python variable. In Jupyter you can use javascript but this does not work in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

It is possible to assign the google colab notebook name to a python variable. In Jupyter you can use javascript but this does not work in colab. I have found examples using %javascript to access the html but these do not appear to work with colab notebooks. So I want to copy the notebook to my google drive and rename it but then assign the new name to a python variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code to get the notebook name.

```py
from requests import get
filename = get('http://172.28.0.2:9000/api/sessions').json()[0]['name']
```

### UPDATE - Jan 2023

The URL has changed from "172.28.0.2" to "172.28.0.12". See the other post for details.

**New code:**

```py
from requests import get
filename = get("http://172.28.0.12:9000/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
```

Or, to adapt if ip is changed again

```py
from requests import get
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname
ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()) # 172.28.0.12
filename = get(f"http://{ip}:9000/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
```

Comment: This workaround doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 2023, korakot's solution needs to be updated to the new URL from "172.28.0.2" to "172.28.0.12". The working code is below:

```py
import requests
filename = requests.get("http://172.28.0.12:9000/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
# Output will be of the form "xyz.ipynb"
```

---

### Alternative: A solution robust to IP changes

```py
colab_ip = %system hostname -I   # uses colab magic to get list from bash
colab_ip = colab_ip[0].strip()   # returns "172.28.0.12"
colab_port = 9000                # could use 6000, 8080, or 9000

import requests
filename = requests.get(f"http://{colab_ip}:{colab_port}/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
# Output will be of the form "xyz.ipynb"
```

---

### Explanation

In case the URL changes again the future, you can find the latest IP address using code from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709565/2879686.
The relevant code is below:

```
# Gives IP address
!hostname -I
print()  # empty line
# Gives IP addresses with port numbers
!sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

The current output for me is:

```
172.28.0.12 

node        7 root   21u  IPv6  19966      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
kernel_ma  35 root    7u  IPv4  19643      0t0  TCP 172.28.0.12:6000 (LISTEN)
colab-fil  65 root    3u  IPv4  19927      0t0  TCP *:3453 (LISTEN)
colab-fil  65 root    4u  IPv6  19929      0t0  TCP *:3453 (LISTEN)
jupyter-n  91 root    4u  IPv4  20144      0t0  TCP 172.28.0.12:9000 (LISTEN)
python3   138 root   23u  IPv4  20719      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45899 (LISTEN)
python3   174 root    3u  IPv4  19440      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:18901 (LISTEN)
python3   174 root    5u  IPv4  20935      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:40271 (LISTEN)
```

Interestingly, there are multiple ports that work:

- 172.28.0.12:6000
- 172.28.0.12:8080
- 172.28.0.12:9000

You can use colab magic to create a solution that is robust to IP changes.
Reference: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics

```py
colab_ip = %system hostname -I   # uses colab magic to get list from bash
colab_ip = colab_ip[0].strip()   # returns "172.28.0.12"
colab_port = 9000                # could use 6000, 8080, or 9000

import requests
filename = requests.get(f"http://{colab_ip}:{colab_port}/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
# Output will be of the form "xyz.ipynb"
```